# how to remove whitespace at the beginning of each element of a Strings array

Tags: java, groovy

I have an array such as `def list = ["pathfinding", "    Gameplay", "Community"]` which I would like to iterate and eliminate the whitespace at the beginning of each element. So I though it would be easy using something like:

```
for(x in list){
    x = x.replace("\\s", "")
    println x
}
```

but I keep getting this output

```
pathfinding
    Gameplay
Community
```

I do now know much about regex what I tried different ones I found here in SO and none worked so I guess the regex is not the problem here... any hints?

Comment: Groovy has method `"".trim()` if I remember correctly so you don't need to mess with regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you can just trim all the elements in the list

```
def trimmedList = list*.trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `replaceAll` instead of `replace` works:

```
for (x in list) {     
    x = x.replaceAll("\\s", "")     
    println x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use String#trim()

```
def list = ["pathfinding", "    Gameplay", "Community"]
for(x in list){
    x = x.trim()
    log(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would trim leading space in Java:

```java
public String trimLeadingWhitespace(String text) {

    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
    else throw new RuntimeException("Unable to match pattern");
}
```

I am using regex to match the whitespace characters.

You can test the above code like this:

```java
@Test
void shouldTrimLeadingWhitespace() {

    String[] array = new String[] { " pathfinding", "    Gameplay", "   Community" };
    for (String entry : array)
    {
        Assertions.assertTrue(entry.startsWith(" "));

        String trimmed = trimLeadingWhitespace(entry);
        Assertions.assertFalse(trimmed.startsWith("\\s"));

        System.out.println("Trimmed entry: " + trimmed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to trim the beginning and not the end, this is also a way:

```
def clean = list.collect { it.dropWhile { it == ' ' } }
```

running:

```
def list = ["pathfinding", "    Gameplay", "Community"]
def clean = list.collect { it.dropWhile { it == ' ' } }
println clean
```

prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
[pathfinding, Gameplay, Community]

─➤
```